# How to map the string as a json key, value pair in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Iam getting the string like *["Check", "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"]* this into the ruby method.

I want the string to be converted into json and pass to the database like
*{"Check" => "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"}*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Hash::[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) (plus `*`):

```
Hash[*["Check", "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"]]
# {"Check"=>"06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"}
```

Or `to_h` if you wrap your array in another array:

```
[["Check", "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"]].to_h
# {"Check"=>"06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a string as you mentioned then you can parse it as JSON, then convert to a hash wrapping it into another array and calling `to_h` on it:

```
> array = JSON.parse('["Check", "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"]')
 => ["Check", "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"] 
> [array].to_h
 => {"Check"=>"06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"}
```

**UPD:**

To work with more items use `each_slice` method:

```
> array = JSON.parse('["check", "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM", "test", "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"]')
 => ["check", "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM", "test", "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"] 
> array.each_slice(2).to_h
 => {"check"=>"06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM", "test"=>"06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"}
```

Comment: It is working, but I will multiple values like below,
["check", "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM", "test", "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"].
I want to split the values into text and time separately and wanted to have it as json as
["check" => "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM", "test" => "06/23/2020 @ 07:15 AM"].
Can you help on this please ?

Comment: Better to mention such details in the question. I updated my answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks!!! How to sort those two based on the date and time which is in value?

Comment: You can do it like this `array.each_slice(2).sort_by { |_, time| Time.strptime(time, '%m/%d/%Y @ %l:%M %p') }.to_h`. Please mark the answer as the correct one if it is.